# CherryPy Facebook Authentication on Google Appengine

Tags: python, cherrypy

I'm trying to port this sample [facebook oauth 2.0 auth](https://github.com/facebook/python-sdk/tree/master/examples/oauth) from [webapp](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/) to cherrypy. however it always return a None value in self.current_user. I think I'm having trouble with settings cookies here. any corrections? see source code [here](http://errorpaste.appspot.com/logs/4001/cherrypy-facebook-authentication-on-google-appengine)

Answer (score 0):

I think that your suspicious about the way that you are setting the cookie are right, you are just building the cookie (the string) and never really use the value, you should use `cherrypy.response.cookie` not `Cookie.BaseCookie`, `set_cookie` should be like this:

```
def set_cookie(name, value, domain=None, path="/", expires=None):
    """Generates and signs a cookie for the give name/value"""
    timestamp = str(int(time.time()))
    value = base64.b64encode(value)
    signature = cookie_signature(value, timestamp)
    cookie = cherrypy.response.cookie
    cookie[name] = "|".join([value, timestamp, signature])
    cookie[name]["path"] = path
    if domain: 
        cookie[name]["domain"] = domain
    if expires:
      cookie[name]["expires"] = email.utils.formatdate(expires,
                                                       localtime=False,
                                                       usegmt=True)
```

Comment: I also asked this question on CherryPy users group and Sylvain made some notes which I will take a look at.  here is the link http://groups.google.com/group/cherrypy-users/browse_thread/thread/e17b1c6deb20b763 btw i'l check back at your code.